# javascript error on html page on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My website is in bootstrap and jquery 2.3.3 whenever i reload my html code. some extra closing brackets are coming at the end of the code.Please check attached screenshot of webpage and also is here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>iRobot India | Roomba Braava</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap.js" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/navtab_scroll.min.js" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
  <script src="js/my_js.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('.carousel').each(function() {
        $(this).carousel({
          interval: false
        });
      });
    });​
  </script>

  <body data-target=".navbar">
    <div class="main-container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 header-nav">
        <div class="navbar-header ">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default container" id="fixednav" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
              </button>
              <div class="text-left">
                <a href="index.html">
                  <img src="images/logo_small.png">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-ex1-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left  text-center">
                <li class="nav-item menuactive on" style="border:none;">
                  <a href="shop.html" class="menu">
                    <span>Shop</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="Vaccummcleaning.html" class="menu">
                    <span>Home Robots</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="Companyprofile.html" class="menu">
                    <span>About iRobot</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="FAQ.html" class="menu">
                    <span>Support</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="contact-us.html" class="menu">
                    <span style="border:none !important;">Contact Us</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="float-nav col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height:22px;"></div>
          <ul class=" ">
            <li><a href="shop.html">Vacuuming</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="mopping.html">Mopping</a>
            </li>
            <li style="border:none !important;"><a href="acceseries.html">Accessories</a>
            </li>
            <li style="border:none !important;" class="gray-panel">
              <div>
                <p>Shopping Cart&nbsp;
                  <a href="#vaccum.html">
                    <img src="images/cart_icon.png">
                  </a>(0)</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 banner-top-whitespace"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bannerimage text-center  top-border bottom-border" style="padding: 0;">
        <p class="text-center"><a href="mopping.html"><span>Free Shipping</span> on all irobot ordres</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height:50px;"></div>
      <div class="row col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center product-detail-wrapper">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-SM-12 col-XS-12" id="popupframe">
            <div class="video-iframe" id="popupdivframe">
              <div class="frameheader text-left">
                <div class="heading-dark-green"><strong>iRobot <sup>®</sup> Roomba 980 <sup>®</sup></strong>
                </div>
                <div class="heading-green-sm"> <strong>Vaccum cleaning Robot</strong>
                </div>
                <i onclick="div_hide()" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="frameimage carousel slide" align="center" id="carousel-ex">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/more images/980/R980_CarpetTransition_lowres.png" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/more images/980/R980_NavigatingFurniture_crop_lowres.png" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/more images/980/R980_UnderBed_lowres.png" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="popupframe-footer" href="#carousel-ex" data-slide="prev">&lt;Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="popupframe-footer" href="#carousel-ex" data-slide="next">Next&gt;</a>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-SM-12 col-XS-12" id="popupframe2">
            <div class="video-iframe" id="popupzoomframe">
              <div class="frameheader text-left">
                <i onclick="div_hide2()" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="framezoomimage carousel slide" align="center" id="carousel-ex1">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-ex" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/irobot-roomba-880-vacuum-cleaning-robot-for-pets-and-allergies.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/pG01-21837072dt2.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/pG01-21837072d1.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="popupframe-footer">
                spin <a href="#carousel-ex1" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#carousel-ex1" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-SM-12 col-XS-12" id="popupframe3">
            <div class="video-iframe" id="popupdivframe">
              <div class="frameheader text-left">
                <div class="heading-dark-green"><strong>iRobot <sup>®</sup> Roomba 980 <sup>®</sup></strong>
                </div>
                <div class="heading-green-sm"><strong> Vaccum cleaning Robot</strong>
                </div>
                <i onclick="div_hide3()" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="frametext text-left">
                <strong>What's In The Box:</strong>
                <br />
                <br />
                <ul>
                  <li>1 iRobot Roomba 980</li>
                  <li>1 Rechargeable Battery</li>
                  <li>1 Home Base Charging Station</li>
                  <li>1 Line Cord</li>
                  <li>2 Dual Mode Virtual Wall Barriers (batteries included)</li>
                  <li>1 Extra AeroForce® High-Efficiency Filter</li>
                  <li>1 Extra Side Brush</li>
                  <li>1-Year Manufacturer's Limited Warranty On Robot, 6-Month Manufacturer's Limited Warranty On Battery</li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                <br />
                <strong>Specifications: </strong> 
                <br />
                <br />
                <span class="para-text-xs">Package Dimensions: 43.3 x 14.7 x 54.7 cm<br />
                                Package Weight: 6.9 Kgs<br />
                                Robot Dimensions: 35 cm in diameter, 9.2 cm in height <br />
                                Robot Weight: 3.94 Kgs
                                <br /><br />
                                
                                * Tested in iRobot's Home Test Lab on hard floors. Run times may vary<br />
                                ** Compared to Roomba 600 and 700 series AeroVac™ systems</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <strong> The iRobot limited warranty shall not apply to failures or problems which are caused by products or equipment not <br /><br />
                                authorized by iRobot Corporation.</strong>
                <br />
                <br />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img src="images/pIRBT1-21837072v38011.png" class="img-responsive" />
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <img src="images/camera-icon-43654.png" class="img-responsive" id="popup" onclick="div_show()">
            <div class="image-caption image-caption-xs">MORE IMAGES</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <img src="images/box.png" class="img-responsive" id="popup" onclick="div_show3()">
            <div class="image-caption image-caption-xs">WHAT'S IN THE BOX</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
            <a class="text-center">
              <button class="btn btn-block btn-watch">Add To Watchlist</button>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
            <a class="text-center">
              <img src="images/mail.png" class="img-responsive" /><span class="image-caption image-caption-xs">EMAIL TO A FREIND</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
            <a class="text-center">
              <img src="images/print.png" class="img-responsive" /><span class="image-caption image-caption-xs">PRINTABLE VIEW</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 text-left content-small">
          <p class="heading-black">iRobot<sup>®</sup> Roomba<sup>®</sup> 980</p>
          <p class="heading-black-small">Vacuum Cleaning Robot</p>
          <p class="para-text-xs text-left">The new Roomba 980 gives you cleaner floors, throughout your entire home, all at the push of a button. Roomba 980 seamlessly navigates an entire level of your home, keeping track of its location and recharging as needed until the job is done.
            The AeroForce® Cleaning System with Carpet Boost automatically increases power on carpets where it's needed most. And with the iRobot HOME App, you can clean and schedule on the go.</p>
          <p class="text-left heading-green-xs"><a href="#specifiaction" class="smoothScroll">Read Full Product Specifications</a>
          </p>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
            <p class="text-left heading-black-xs"><span class="para-text-xs">Price:</span> &#x20B9; 64900.00</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8  col-sm-8 col-xs-8 text-left">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 social-button">
              <a class="text-left buttonhover">
                <img src="images/like.png" class="img-responsive" />
              </a>
              <a class="text-right share buttonhover">
                <img src="images/share.png" class="img-responsive" />
              </a>
              <p class="heading-black-xs views">1,443,00 People like this</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left pinit">
              <a class="text-left">
                <img src="images/pintit.png" class="img-responsive" />
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-left">
              <p class="heading-black-xs">QTY:
                <input type="text" style="width: 23px;color: #000;text-align: center;" id="eaBar-quantity" name="eaBar-quantity" maxlength="2" size="1" value="1">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left float-button" style="">
              <p align="center">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="images/addToCart_sm.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
                <!--<span>-OR-</span><br/>&nbsp;
               <a href="#"><img src="images/checkout-logo-small.png" /></a></p>-->
                <p class="heading-black-xs"><span class="blue-text-xs">In-Stock, usually ships in 7 - 10 full bus. days <span><a class="heading-green-xs-bold" href="#">(Details)</a></span></span>
                  <br>
                  <span class="heading-black-xs-bold">AVAIBILITY:</span>
                  <br />
                  <span class="heading-black-xs-bold">Sales Tax:</span>Sales tax will be added at checkout.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 product-detail-right-panel">
          <a href="http://irobot.netmahiti.in/owneroverview.aspx?id=cHJvc3JzMDAwMDAwMDA1" target="_blank">
            <div class="product-vedio"></div>
          </a>
          <a href="FAQ.html" target="_blank">
            <div class="green-border text-center green-text-xs col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <p>FAQ</p>
            </div>
          </a>

          <a href="wi-fi-information.html" target="_blank">
            <div class="green-border text-center green-text-xs col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <p>Wi-Fi Information
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="http://irobot.netmahiti.in/owneroverview.aspx?id=cHJvc3JzMDAwMDAwMDA1" target="_blank">
            <div class="green-border text-center green-text-xs col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <p>900 Series Owner's Center</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class=" col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pro-detail" style=" font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;">
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <p class="heading-black-small"><b>TOP SELLING ACCESSORIES</b>
          </p>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <p>
              <img src="images/pIRBT1-17181539v380.png" class="img-responsive">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
            <br />
            <p class="heading-black-small-bold">3 Replacement AeroForce<sup>®</sup> High-Efficiency Filters For Roomba<sup>®</sup> 800 and 900 Series</p>
            <p class="heading-black-xs">Price:<span class="heading-green-xs"><b>&#x20B9; 1490.00</b></span>
            </p>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <p class="heading-black-xs">QTY:
                <input type="text" style="width: 23px;color: #000;text-align: center;" id="eaBar-quantity" name="eaBar-quantity" maxlength="2" size="1" value="1">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
              <p>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="images/addToCart_smm.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <-- compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>>>>>>>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ZB8.png)

Comment: Change </html>>>>>>> to </html>

Comment: Remove last line 
`</html>>>>>>>` by 
`</html>`

Answer (score 0):

Delete extra `>>>>>` from `html` closing tag at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a javascript error it is a typo error Remove last line `</html>>>>>>>` by `</html>`

Answer (score 0):

There's `</html>>>>>>>` at the end instead of `</html>` that's why you see the extra `>>>>>>`